# Deleted but still defined?

Tags: perl, hash, undefined

I'm dealing with a hash of hashes in Perl and I'm running into some problems. After a while that my code is running, it generates a hash of hashes that looks like something similar to this:

```
my %book = (
    +1 => {
        27 => 100,
        24 => 1000,
    },
    -1 => {
        30 => 200,
        31 => 500,
    }
);
```

After processing some more data, the code ends up removing two entries of the hash by using the following line of code:

```
delete $book{-1}{30};
delete $book{-1}{31};
```

Hence, the hash should be half empty. However, when later on in my code I run the following if statement:

```
if ((defined $book{+1}) && (defined $book{-1})){
    do A
}else{
    do B
}
```

my code ends up doing "thing A" rather than "thing B" which he should do since the "-1" side of the hash has been deleted. How is this possible? And, most importantly, how to solve this problem?

Comment: surprised the answers don't just suggest changing your if to test `&& %{ $book{-1} }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you delete the two entries inside `%{$books{-1}}`, the hash reference `$books{-1}` still exists even though it's empty.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %book = (
    +1 => {
        27 => 100,
        24 => 1000,
    },
    -1 => {
        30 => 200,
        31 => 500,
    }
);

delete $book{-1}{30};
delete $book{-1}{31};

use Data::Dump;
dd \%book;
```

Outputs:

```
{ -1 => {}, 1 => { 24 => 1000, 27 => 100 } }
```

If you'd like to trim that entry, you'll have to code explicit logic for that

```
# Trim Hash
my @empty_keys = grep {!%{$book{$_}}} keys %book;
delete $book{$_} for @empty_keys;
```

**Update**

As ysth suggested, one alternative solution would be to test if any of the hash keys were empty instead:

```
if (! grep {!$book{$_} || !%{$book{$_}}} qw(1 -1)) {
    print "A\n";
} else {
    print "B\n";
}
```

Comment: +1: Thats a pretty nice approach to grab entries from `HoH` for `keys` that have no values. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Or just: `delete @book{ grep !%{$book{$_}}, keys(%book) };`

Comment: Note that `!%{$book{$_}}` will be slower than `!keys(%{$book{$_}})` on older versions of Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I went online to figure out how does the grep function works and I'm still a little confused to what does your code do. Which part of the code tells PERL to see whether the key is empty? Is it the exclamation mark? Also, if I understand it correctly, the problem with my code was that I never deleted the "-1" key in the %book hash and only deleted the "30" and "31" keys of the "sub" hash, correct?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct.  After you did `delete $book{-1}{31};`, you could've also done `delete $book{-1} if !%{$book{-1}};`.  The code I demonstrated just did the general case instead, looking for any hash references that were empty.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing superfluous hash elements, I would prefer to make the code that used `%book` resilient to empty hashes, which isn't so hard to do in general

I would also be very wary of using a hash with numeric keys, because there are many strings that could represent the same number. For instance, although `'1' == '1.0'` is *true*, `'1' eq '1.0'` is *false*, and if the values were used as hash keys they would refer to different elements

With those provisos, I would write the following

I am sorry that I have only a tablet to work on at present, and the IDE doesn't allow me to copy the output text to paste here. But it is tested and working

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %book = (
  +1 => {
    27 => 100,
    24 => 1000,
  },
  -1 => {
    30 => 200,
    31 => 500,
  }
);

# $book{-1} becomes an empty hash
delete $book{-1}{30};
delete $book{-1}{31};

# remove elements that have no content
for (keys %book) {
  delete $book{$_} unless keys %{ $book{$_} };
}

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper \%book;
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin for your reply. Could you please explain me what does `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` do?

Comment: It changes the output format so that strings are shown in double-quotes, and whitespace and control characters are expressed using their escape-sequence equivalents. It makes it very much easier to spot trailing newlines and embedded tab characters

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. I don't understand why does your code not work anymore if I remove the "keys" in your for statement; If I re-write your for loop as `for (keys %book){ if (!%{$book{$_}}){delete $book{$_}}` I don't need to specify that those are keys??

Comment: @g_puffo: A simple hash like `%book` expands into the list `key1`, `value1`, `key2`, `value2`, `key3`, `value3`, ... So every other item is an element *value*. using `keys %books` gives `key1`, `key2`, `key3`, ... instead, which is what is wanted

Comment: I see; I thought that since you have `keys` in your `for` loop that this implied that PERL was going to look only through the keys of the hash. Thanks.